# Bad syntax on MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

it says unexpected "="... What should I rewrite? Thanks

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM soubory, users
WHERE id='".$id."'" AND soubory.users_id = users.id );
```

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting above not give it away?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the second `"` after `$id."'`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM soubory, users WHERE soubory.users_id='".$id."' AND soubory.users_id = users.id");
```

Comment: It says --> Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

But when its just without and query, its fine.

Comment: Column 'id' in where clause is **ambiguous** because `WHERE id` is ambiguous. Try `where users.id` or `where soubory.users_id`

Comment: @frky: you'll need to swap the `WHERE id =` to `WHERE users.id =`, assuming the `id` is for the user and not soubory. If it's the other way around, use the other one.

Comment: @frky you can use `WHERE users.id` or `WHERE soubory.users_id` like the answer.